# jQuery lines are throwing "$.browser is undefined" error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have been working on a different branch of a Rails 3.2 application I have, and when I switched back to the main application, nothing is working. Firebug tells me I have a bunch of different jQuery plugins that are just failing with this error:

```
$.browser is undefined
```

This call is being made from 4 different plugins, and they are all failing, which is causing my page to quit rendering. I can't figure out the problem. My application.js looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
//= require jquery.ui.sortable
//= require jquery.ui.tabs
//= require jquery.ui.dialog
//= require jquery.ui.Multiselect
//= require jquery.ui.effect-highlight  
//= require jquery.corner
//= require jquery.cycle.lite
//= require jquery.deserialize
//= require jquery.form
//= require jquery.ifixpng
//= require jquery.livequery.min
//= require jquery.Localisation.min
//= require jquery.query-2.1.7
//= require jquery.shadow
//= require jquery.tablesorter.min
//= require jquery.tools.min
//= require jquery.urldecoder.min
//= require magiczoom
//= require colorpicker
//= require jquery.ScrollTo.min
//= require jquery.ba-bbq.min
//= require_tree .
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.api.fnSetFilteringDelay
```

Any help is much appreciated. I'm certain I'm missing something simple here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you are using jQuery 1.9+ which already dropped the $.browser. You need to use the [jQuery migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/).

Comment: Or... stop using `$.browser`.

Comment: @Brad not so easy when you're using plugins that depend on it

Comment: @Brad if it's his plugins that use it he doesn't have much of a chance, unless he also drops the plugins

Comment: Of course it isn't easy!  But better to fix it now than deal with it later.  It's been deprecated for a long time.  Stop using broken plugins.  Update the ones that you can.

Comment: Alternate solution: use an older version of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Browser is deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and has been removed at jQuery 1.9

See [the documenation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) for more info.

> Description: Contains flags for the useragent, read from navigator.userAgent. We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery.

As they say, use the [navigation.userAgent JavaScript property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.userAgent) to detect the browser.
Or use an older version of jQuery, but that would not be my first choice.